# Constructor is not called in C++

Tags: c++, constructor

This is the code.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Item{
   double itemPrice;
   int qty;
   public:
   Item(){
      cout<<"Enter Item Price : "<<endl;
      cin>>itemPrice;
      cout<<"Enter QTY : " <<endl;
      cin>>qty;
   }
   double getItemTotal(){
      return itemPrice*qty;
   }
   };

   class Order{
      int index;
      int orderId;
      double orderValue;
      Item items[20];
  public:
      Order(){
          index=0;
          cout<<"\nEnter Order ID : ";
          cin>>orderId;
  }
  void viewOrderDetails(){
      for(int j=0;j<20;j++){
         Item ii=items[j];
         orderValue=orderValue+ii.getItemTotal();
      }
      cout<<"Order ID   : "<<orderId<<endl;
      cout<<"Order Value   : "<<orderValue<<endl;
  }

  void addToOrder(Item i){
      if(index<19){
         items[index]=i;
         index=index+1;
      }else{
         cout<<"\nOrder Full";
      }
  }
};

int main(){
   Order odr1;

   Item i1;
   Item i2;

   odr1.addToOrder(i1);
   odr1.addToOrder(i2);

   odr1.viewOrderDetails();

   return 0;
}
```

I want to run the constructor of Order class.
But it runs the Constructor of Item class.
I checked the code many times and did a research.But I cant seem any wrong in the code.
I am using CodeBlocks IDE with GCC Compiler( MingGW ).
I appreciate if anybody can help me with this. 
Thanks.

Comment: A research? What did you find? What did you try?

Comment: `Order` contains an array of 20 `Item`s that get constructed before the body of the `Order`'s constructor runs.

Comment: It's not normally a good idea to have any user interaction in the constructor.

Comment: What feedback do you get that makes you think that your code does not do what you want?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I googled "Constructor is not called in C++" and similar things. But I didnt find any answer.
I am new to C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor of your Order class will get callled.

```
Item items[20];  // <-- here you actually create 20 Items and the constructor for each Item will be called. Then the Order Constructor will get called.
```

You could use `std::list<Item> items;` instead of `Item items[20]`. In that case you don't actually create an Item (and therefore its constructor will not get called) you just create a container where you can store your items.

Anyway, it is bad practice to do what you do in your constructor. A constructor should initialize the object and it should run fast. So create a method instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your Order class is:

```
  class Order{
      int index;
      int orderId;
      double orderValue;
      Item items[20];
  public:
      Order(){

       // the body of the constructor
```

Your `Order` class contains an array of 20 `Item`s.

Before the code in the constructor executes, all class members have to be constructed, first.

Since your `Order` class contains 20 `Item`s, each one of them must be constructed first, and `Item`'s default constructor is going to get called twenty times, before the body of the `Order`'s constructor starts executing. This is how C++ works.

This is the explanation for why you're seeing the code in `Item`'s default constructor getting apparently executed before the code in `Order`'s default constructor.

Instead of:

```
 Item items[20];
```

you need to use a vector:

```
 std::vector<Item> items;
```

and have `addToOrder()` use `push_back()` to initialize the vector.

Comment: Okay I understood it.
Thanks for your support. :)
I really appreciate it.